# How do I show an excerpt in table view at a WordPress website?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I write this HTML code in Excerpt tab at WordPress website

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th> Firstname </th>
    <th> Lastname </th>
    <th> Age </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> Jill </td>
    <td> Smith </td>
    <td> 50 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> Eve </td>
    <td> Jackson </td>
    <td> 94 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image: code image as i write]

But it Display me like this without table view

[image: error result image]

Here is my Excerpt setting

[image: Excerpt setting image 1]
[image: Excerpt setting image 2]

I want it show me in a table format.